# Using a bean inside onException().onWhen()

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm using this book, Camel in Action 2nd Edition. It has an example that I'm using a a guide to catch an http error and decide what the http status code is. However, I get an error that indicates there is not "bean" method.

The example is available here, part of the errata (p510) https://raw.githubusercontent.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/master/errata.txt

The error describe on the errata isn't my problem, btw. I just can't compile the code when I have bean() inside onWhen().

What am I doing wrong here?

EmailRouter.java

```
.doTry()
    .log("Initial Header: ${headers.Authorization} ${body}")
    .to("https://test.net/rest/api/email")
.doCatch(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
    .onWhen(bean(FailureBean.class, "httpAuthFail"))  // Causes "The method bean(Class<FailureBean>, String) is undefined for the type EmailRouter"
    .log("Before InOnly: ${headers.Authorization} ${body}")
    .to("direct:dead?exchangePattern=InOnly")
    .setBody(simple("${headers.MessageBody}"))
    .setHeader("Authorization", exchangeProperty("token"))
    .log("Newly Set Header: ${headers.Authorization} ${body}")
    .to("https://test.net/rest/api/email")
.end()
```

FailureBean.java

```
package com.bw.beans;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.camel.ExchangeException;
import org.apache.camel.Headers;
import org.apache.camel.http.base.HttpOperationFailedException;

public class FailureBean {

    public static boolean httpAuthFail(@ExchangeException HttpOperationFailedException cause) {
        int code = cause.getStatusCode();
        if (code == 401) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **`bean` option was removed** from Camels [BeanLanguage](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/bean-language.html) in Camel 3. You can find it (deprecated) in the [Camel 2.x docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/languages/bean-language.html).

That simply means that instead of

```
.onWhen(bean(FailureBean.class, "httpAuthFail"))
```

you **have to use the `method` option**

```
.onWhen(method(FailureBean.class, "httpAuthFail"))
```

The 2nd edition of [Camel in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition) was released before Camel 3.x so some of the **code examples have to be adapted** for Camel 3.x. The [Camel migration guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html) can be very helpful for this.